# SentrySDK VB.NET initialization example

Tags: c#, vb.net, sentry, c#-to-vb.net

How do I convert the SentrySDK C# initialization code to VB.NET?

```
using (SentrySdk.Init(o =>
{
    o.Dsn = "https://examplePublicKey@o0.ingest.sentry.io/0";
    o.MaxBreadcrumbs = 50;
    o.Debug = true;
}))
{
}
```

**Update**

I get the following error using the code provided by Dave below.

[image]

**Update 2:**

The error happens with SentrySDK 2, but is resolved with SentrySDK 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion is just in the placement of the lambda I think. The VB equivalent is just:

```
Using SentrySdk.Init(Sub(o)
    o.Dsn = "https://examplePublicKey@o0.ingest.sentry.io/0"
    o.MaxBreadcrumbs = 50
    o.Debug = True
End Sub)
End Using
```

Comment: FYI: This works with SDK 3, but does not work with SDK 2.

Comment: 2.0 had a Dsn class. Just do o.Dsn = new Dsn("...")